# cypher output in JSON format

Tags: neo4j

Input Data

```
MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n;
CREATE (p:Provider {id:1, specialty:"Cardiology",        pcp:0});
CREATE (p:Provider {id:2, specialty:"Internal Medicine", pcp:1});
CREATE (p:Provider {id:3, specialty:"Family Practice",   pcp:1});
CREATE (p:Provider {id:4, specialty:"Radiology",         pcp:0});

MATCH (p1:Provider {id:1}), (p2:Provider {id:2}) CREATE 
        (p1)-[:SHARED {mbrid:1}]->(p2),
        (p1)-[:SHARED {mbrid:2}]->(p2),
        (p1)-[:SHARED {mbrid:2}]->(p2),
        (p1)-[:SHARED {mbrid:3}]->(p2);
MATCH (p1:Provider {id:2}), (p2:Provider {id:3}) CREATE 
        (p1)-[:SHARED {mbrid:4}]->(p2),
        (p1)-[:SHARED {mbrid:5}]->(p2);
MATCH (p1:Provider {id:1}), (p2:Provider {id:3}) CREATE 
        (p1)-[:SHARED {mbrid:6}]->(p2);
MATCH (p1:Provider {id:1}), (p2:Provider {id:4}) CREATE 
        (p1)-[:SHARED {mbrid:9}]->(p2),
        (p1)-[:SHARED {mbrid:10}]->(p2),
        (p1)-[:SHARED {mbrid:11}]->(p2),
        (p1)-[:SHARED {mbrid:12}]->(p2),
        (p1)-[:SHARED {mbrid:12}]->(p2);

CREATE INDEX ON :Provider(id);
```

Query

```
MATCH (p1:Provider)-[s:SHARED]-(p2:Provider)
WHERE  p1.id<p2.id and (p1.pcp=0 or (p1.pcp=1 and p2.pcp=0))
WITH p1, p2, count(distinct s.mbrid) as cnt
WHERE cnt>1
RETURN p1, p2, cnt;
```

Output

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| p1                                         | p2                                                | cnt |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[0]{id:1,specialty:"Cardiology",pcp:0} | Node[1]{pcp:1,id:2,specialty:"Internal Medicine"} | 3   |
| Node[0]{id:1,specialty:"Cardiology",pcp:0} | Node[3]{id:4,specialty:"Radiology",pcp:0}         | 4   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need the output to be in the following format.  Observe that node with id 3 is not listed below since it is not in the output.  Also, the output nodes are indexed 0,1,2 and used in the links

```
{
    "nodes" : [
        {
            "specialty" : "Cardiology",
            "pcp" : 0
        },
        {
            "specialty" : "Internal Medicine",
            "pcp" : 1
        },
        {
            "specialty" : "Radiology",
            "pcp" : 0
        }
    ],
    "links" : [
        {
            "source" : 0,
            "target" : 1,
            "value" : 3
        },
        {
            "source" : 0,
            "target" : 2,
            "value" : 4
        }
    ]
}
```

I would appreciate any inputs/pointers on how to create this.

Answer (score 0):

Refine your query to output only the nodes you require, then in the Neo browser click the 'Export to File' button (next to the query text you have just entered). Then select Export JSON